# datatables - on load show last page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

i would like to load a page with datatables and on load to show the last page in pagination.
now i have a button and press it to move to last page.

[demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/pdoo0khs/1/)

my js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": url
    });

    $('#lastpage').on('click', function () {
        table.page('last').draw(false);
    });
     });
```

Thank you

Update 1:

new demo with the use of a timer, first load page 1 and then move to last page.

[demo page - timer refresh buttons](http://live.datatables.net/jobihota/3)

js

```
var url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bWIUWNtazS?indent=2";

$(document).ready(function () {

var table = $('#example').dataTable({
ajax: {
url : 'http://dnses.net/project88751/api/expenses.php?action=getExpenses',
dataType: 'json'
},
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').css({ 'overflow' : 'hidden', 'overflow-y' : 'auto' });
setTimeout(function() {
var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
api.page('last').draw('page');} , 40);
},

});
});
```

update 2:

is this code, i managed to load data from first page but pagination showing last page!!

[demo page - showing data from first page](http://live.datatables.net/jobihota/4)

js:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $("#example").DataTable({
"ajax": {
"url" : "http://dnses.net/project88751/api/expenses.php?action=getExpenses",
"dataType": "json"
},
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
    initComplete: function() {
      var api = this.api();
      var info = api.page.info();
      api.page(info.pages - 1).draw(false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I posted an answer, realized it ([page('last')](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page())) was not helpful, and so deleted it. But VasoulaK posted a link to a demo in the comments to the answer - here is that link:  [live.datatables.net/jobihota/3/edit](http://live.datatables.net/jobihota/3/edit). I did not want the link to be lost.

Comment: Because this is a server-side Data Table, the problem is how to elegantly deal with the initial call from the client to the server - when the client does not yet know anything about the number of rows of data the server will be returning.